# What is the problem in this code?

Tags: equations, matrices

```
 \begin{doublespace}
    \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{cccc}}
            {\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}\\
            {\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}
            \end{array}} \right)    
    \end{doublespace}
```

Comment: There are many problems, but if you really want help, please consider providing us with a code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot Missing $ inserted. \end{doublespace}

Comment: essentially you need to embrace the matrix with $$ $$ or \ [ \ ]

Comment: I was answering with that detail, but you were faster...+1 :=)@marmot

Comment: @santimirandarp Sorry, was not intentional. (Saw your comment only when I was posting my answer....)

Comment: @marmot np we are just having fun

Answer (score 4):

After seeing the typeset result with no added space, I agree that it would be quite contrived. There is a simpler solution than trying with `doublespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh[2t] &  0         & \sinh[2t] &  0         \\[2ex]
0         &  \cosh[2t] & 0         & -\sinh[2t] \\[2ex]
\sinh[2t] &  0         & \cosh[2t] &  0         \\[2ex]
0         & -\sinh[2t] & 0         &  \cosh[2t]
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

You had several useless braces and also `\left` and `\right` tokens, which I removed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OK, here we go then. The least thing you need to do is to switch to math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\begin{document}

You seem to \emph{really} want local doublespace. Well, OK, here we go.
\begin{doublespace}
\[    \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{cccc}}
            {\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}\\
            {\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}
            \end{array}} \right)    \]
\end{doublespace}           
However, I'd use a \verb|pmatrix| environment.
\begin{doublespace}
\[    \begin{pmatrix}
            {\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}\\
            {\sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0\\
            0&{ - \sinh \left[ {2t} \right]}&0&{\cosh \left[ {2t} \right]}
      \end{pmatrix}    \]
\end{doublespace}           
\end{document}
```

[image]

You're sure you want something like this?